# linux-get Task status of a PID in C++

Tags: c++, linux

I have a programm which I want to get a PID of a task and returns its status (running,stoped and...) and its exit status (dead,zombie and..)

I know C# and java but does not know about linux and C++ much,This is what I have found ...

```
#include<linux/kernel.h>
#include<linux/syscalls.h>
asmlinkage int sys_pidstat(int pid){

      int status = 0;

      int rtn = kill(pid, 0);
      if (rtn == -1 && errno == ESRCH)
      {
          return 0;
      }

      rtn = waitpid(pid, &status, WNOHANG | WUNTRACED | WCONTINUED);

      if (rtn == 0) // still live
      {
        return 0;
      }

      std::cout << "Probably success. Errno: " << errno << ". StrError: " << strerror(errno) << std::endl;
      if (WIFEXITED(status))
      {
        return 1;
      }

      return 0;
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    ;
}
```

I found that waitpid may return the status..But could not mpliment it..waitpid needs a pid as input...What should I give as pid?
It would be great if some one helps me and gives me some hints how to do it?
Thank you so much

Comment: Read the man page. If you don't understand something written there, ask.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`waitpid()` waits for a child process to terminate. It has nothing to do with the status of some arbitrary process that has no relation whatsover to this process.

The thing about Linux is that it's not some mysterious black box, whose workings are a deep held secret. If someone wants to know how to do something at Linux, all they have to do is look at the source.

I'm sure you know how to use the `ps` command, which does exactly what you're trying to do.

You can look at the source code of the `ps` command on https://gitlab.com/procps-ng/procps and see how `ps` does this, then do the same thing yourself.

Comment: Thank you for your hint..I looked at ps command and it seems it is exactly what I mean..I should try to learn how to use them..Thanks..